# getView() gets called multiple times and changes state of listview to initial state

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So basically, I have a custom listview with like, dislike and few other buttons which change their state on getting clicked. Now the problem I'm facing is that when I click on say, the like button the query gets passed (even in the backend) and it gets liked successfully but as soon as I scroll up or down that particular list item, it returns to its initial state which it was when the list was loaded. I've looked for many solutions, made the layout as fill_parent but still didn't work. Please someone help me out!

P.S I have attached 2 images, 1) when I like and the counter changes from 1 to 2.  2) when I scroll down and back up it changes back to 1

[image: when I like the list item]

[image: when I scroll up/down and return to the item]

XML Code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lsk"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#34495e"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#34495e"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"

        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
      app:elevation="6dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/upc" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layoutqaqq"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
       >


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvScribe"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
             />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter Code -

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("sd","getView " + position + " " + convertView);

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
        final ImageButton collec;

        if(convertView==null){
            Log.e("in", "" + "null");

        }else {
            Log.e("in", "" + "not null");

        }

        if(item.getViewType()==2) {
            Log.e("in", "" + (feedItems.size() + (feedItems.size() / 9)));
            if (convertView == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adview, null);
            NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("0FF63ABD3E239F0EF3B0F21A90772205").build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            //n=n+6;
        } else {

            if (convertView == null)
                Log.e("conver",""+convertView);
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
            ss = new SharedPrefs(context);
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            TextView tt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView meme = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ImageView profilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
            final ImageButton like = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final ImageButton dlike = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            final TextView co = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.te);
             collec = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            ImageButton comm = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            final ImageButton rep = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            tag = "" + like.getTag();
            imgLoader = new ImageLoaderr(context);
        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: Your code is too confusing and too much to say where the issue is. But one tip I can give is, use RecyclerView which has has the ViewHolder pattern. Views in a ListView or RecyclerView are reused, that means destroyed after they are not visible and recreated after visible again. That happens in your case. See here how to use RecyclerView: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-recyclerview-example and https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html. If you really want to stay at listView, see here:https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-viewholder-pattern-example/

Comment: @Opiatefuchs thanks for replying! I reduced the code for your readability. RecyclerView will solve the issue? You said views in it are reused too.

Comment: yes, they will be reused too, but the RecyclerView has the viewholder pattern implemented which makes it a lot more easy. You should consider to use it, it´s not much work to switch from ListView to RecyclerView, it´s nearly the same....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs ok I'm on it. Will I face the state getting changed in it or will it work as I want it to without making any other changes? I'm following the link you provided

Comment: it depends on how you save the state of your item. Usually it should work, because everytime the view comes up again, the state should be requested again.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs thank you so much man, I did it!!

Comment: you´re welcome...